# $resource.query( ) error function not working during unit testing

Tags: angularjs, resources

I'm developing angular web app.
Below is a method in my controller, which will set fetchPlayersFailed to true when error happends:

```
$scope.fetchAllPlayers = function() {
    $scope.players = PlayerFact.query({
            active: true
        },
        undefined,
        function() {
            console.log('set fetchPlayersFailed to true');
            $scope.fetchPlayersFailed = true;
        }
    );
};
```

But when I run unit tests, error happens at this method, below is the spec I write:

```
  it('fetchAllPlayers: should set fetchPlayersFailed to true when error happens', function() {
    httpBackend.expectGET('/api/players?active=true').respond(500);
    scope.fetchAllPlayers();
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(scope.fetchPlayersFailed).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Here's the error:

```
Chrome 32.0 (Windows) Controller: PlayerCtrl fetchAllPlayers: should set fetchPl
ayersFailed to true when error happens FAILED
        Expected false to equal true.
        Error: Expected false to equal true.
            at null.<anonymous> (C:/Users/I056958/Documents/My Own/javascript wo
rkspace/redjoker/test/spec/controllers/player.js:111:38)
```

**Why is fetchPlayersFailed not being set to true??**

Comment: Is message `set fetchPlayersFailed to true` logged into console?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest whenGET('url').respond(500) in your test since your are not testing the call in your test.
Also if PlayerFact is a service that returns a $resource object I think it's better to mock it.

Your problem is with your function in query, it's the success callback and not the error handler, that is if PlayerFact is a $resource object. 
Here is your updated code:

```
    $scope.fetchAllPlayers = function() {
        $scope.players = PlayerFact.query({
            active: true
        },
        undefined,
        function(){
        },
        function() {
            console.log('set fetchPlayersFailed to true');
            $scope.fetchPlayersFailed = true;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's exactly what the problem is.

Comment: But I'm a bit confused,according to the official angular document:                                                     `HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])`                                                             So query is using GET action, that means there should only be 3 parameters followed. **1st param**: {active: true} ,**2nd param**: undefined, (this one should be the success call back).  **3rd param**: function(){},(this one should be the error call back).  Is there some misunderstanding here??

Comment: @TestersGonnaTest do you know how to unit test the above function?  A $resource with query params?  I'm trying to figure this out, but can't find out how. Thanks